# Is there any difference between assemblies compiled from WebApplication and ClassLibrary projects?

Tags: reflection, assemblies

In other words, if I have a compiled dll file, is there a way to find out (using Reflection) whether this dll is produced from a WebApplication, ClassLibrary or another project type? Is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no practical difference, but you might be able to tell them apart based on the names of various classes and methods. For example, the presence of a `Page_Load` method probably indicates that it's a web application.

Comment: Also, there would usually be classes inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page.